# first time only i want to show the bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, session, twitter-bootstrap-3, local-storage

Here i want to do when ever user comes to first time in my page i want to display modal in this page ,suppose user want for second page and again come page to first page also that modal should not show, i tried lot but i am unable to get answer, any help me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isshow = localStorage.getItem('isshow');
    if (isshow== null) {
        localStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);

        // Show popup here
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
    else{
    alert('else part');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
 <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>-->

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use Javascript cookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Or, if you want to use cookies with your server side language, that's fine too.  Which language?

Comment: What actually doesn't works? Your code seems ok. I've copied it to this fiddle and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/mb81ngmd/. Run it more than one time, no alert it shown.

Comment: @pendo please don't. In OP's case the localStorage is the best option.

Comment: For me nothing is comming like modal not opening

Comment: The advantage of using server side is that if you want the cookie to last more than just the browser session, you must use those.  If every time I come to a site I get the same popup, I'd stop going to that site.  If you only want it for the browser session, then @DontVoteMeDown is correct that javascript cookies are just fine, as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Works fine for me too.  If you're in Chrome, check to settings -> Advanced Settings -> Content Settings -> All cookies and site data.  Search for your domain that you're working on, in my case it's test.localtest.me.  Delete the local storage cookie.  Maybe you already have the cookie set and that's why you can't see it.

Comment: For me it is going to else condition

Comment: @pendo see difference between localStorage and sessionStorage..

Comment: In my case which one i have to use

Comment: @  pendo , i tried your idea , i removed my cookies and run this page it is working , then then i closed the browser again i run the same page but not comming

Comment: @ DontVoteMeDown, i checked your fiddle answer it is working fine , but same code i implemented in my localhost but not working , what is the issue???

Comment: @Swamym  Are you sure you closed all your browser windows?  When you reopen your browser, go check your cookies and see if it's there before you reload the page.

Comment: How it is possible,every time user can't clear the cookies and all

Comment: i opened incognito window  means it is working fine , mozila means new private window i opened means it will working

Answer (score 2):

Please check this fiddle link. [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/y1fznf9L/) your code is working fine and its good to use localstorage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isshow = localStorage.getItem('isshow');
    if (isshow === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('isshow', 1);
        // Show popup here
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } else {
      alert('else part');
    }
});
```